# Grails, can not add detail record to master record

Tags: grails, master-detail

I have the following two classes:

```
class ProdBuffer {

    static hasMany = [plannedVolumes: PlannedVolume]

    def beforeInsert() {
        for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
            addToPlannedVolumes(week:i, volume: 0)
        }
    }
```

> This part caused the error

```
/*  
   weekStart               nullable: true,
       validator: { val, obj -> 
          if (obj.id) {
            // don't check existing instances
            return
          }
          (val as int) >= obj.getCurrentWeek()}
*/          
}

class PlannedVolume {
    static belongsTo = [prodBuffer: ProdBuffer]
    Integer week
    Double  volume

}
```

When I create a new ProdBuffer it should create 9 PlannedVolume records. 
But the PlannedBufferController errors when it tries to save ProdBuffer:
Like:

```
URI
    /prodBuffer/save
Class
    java.lang.NullPointerException
Message
    null

Around line 49 of grails-app\controllers\com\buffer\ProdBufferController.groovy

46:            return
47:        }
48:
49:>>>>        prodBuffer.save flush:true
50:
51:        request.withFormat {
52:            form multipartForm {
```

I have also tried to create the plannedVolume before adding it but it gives the same error all time.

STACKTRACE:

```
Stacktrace follows:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:210)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:187)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.addEntity(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.makeEntityManaged(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.onSaveOrUpdate(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:651)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:643)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:391)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.onSaveOrUpdate(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:651)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:643)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:638)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi$_performSave_closure3.doCall(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:242)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:243)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:187)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:110)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.performSave(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:241)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.save(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:158)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:151)
    at com.buffer.ProdBufferController.$tt__save(ProdBufferController.groovy:49)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Comment: can you show the full error stack please

Comment: Ok, I added it at the end.

Comment: Can you try `addToPlannedVolumes( week: i as Integer, volume: 0 as Double )`

Comment: I changed it to:             addToPlannedVolumes(week:0 as Integer, volume:0 as Double)
Restarted the app but I get the same error

Comment: Seems related to https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10604

Comment: Added the part that I didn't show in the master class. It was a custom validation that isn't needed anymore and I could just comment it and then everything was ok again. Thank's for your help!